# Как узнать дату последнего редактирования и размер файла PhoneGap?

Tags: phonegap, jquery, android, ios, javascript

Может кто-то подсказать, как такое сделать? Хотя бы примерный код или что то похожее?

Comment: тыкаешь на файл правой кнопкой миши... Оо

Comment: та при помощи фонГепа и джаваскрипта

Comment: @dajver - сколько уже можно тупитьс 1им JS API, ужас

Comment: я понимаю что апи, как его к моему проекту использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [W3.org](http://W3.org): [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)
- PhoneGap API: [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html)
- HTML5 Rocks: [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)
- Статья о [PhoneGap's File API](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/9/PhoneGaps-File-API), там же есть готовый код.

ЗЫ разбаньтесь в гугле.

Comment: Так я пример кода спрашиваю, я не пойму, как мне его заюзать.

Comment: Из ссылки @Yura Ivanov.

    function metadataFile(m) {
        logit("File was last modified "+m.modificationTime+"<p/>");    
    }
    
    function doMetadataFile(e) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create:true}, function(f) {
            f.getMetadata(metadataFile,onError);
        }, onError);
    }

Правда чтоль лень ссылки посмотреть и прочитать что там написано? Или Вы только код пишете, теорию совершенно не читаете?

Comment: Иногда читаю, если прижмет, а так пишу код, не читая. Спасибо.